# Elasticsearch Field expansion matches too many fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting the following error when running my elastic search queries.

> Field expansion matches too many fields, got: 1775. This will be limited starting with version 7.0 of Elasticsearch. The limit will be detemined by the `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` setting which is currently set to 1024. You should look at lowering the maximum number of fields targeted by a query or increase the above limit while being aware that this can negatively affect your clusters performance.

Here is an example of one of my queries that throws this error is:

```
def searchQuery = [
    "query" : [
        "bool" : [
            "must" : [
              [ "match" : ["bodyContent_o.item.component.objectId" : objectId] ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
```

My understanding is that by using "match" I'm targeting a specific field and it shouldn't trigger this error, so what am I doing wrong?

Any direction or clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me the answer for `curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mapping?pretty | grep type | wc -l` ?

Comment: The response is '4'

Comment: Please add mapping and sample doc

Comment: Have you found any explanation for this? I have a similar situation and I'm wondering about the same thing.